# is there any tool that can show the execution path of the classloaders?

Tags: java

I am sure lot of people are familiar with `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and I am trying to debug that error for one my application.

I fail to understand what execution path classloaders take when I run my application even though I read some tutorials prior to asking this question. Now, I do know how to fix the problem (I can simple add the jar where the missing class belongs to the classpath and that fixes the problem) however I fail to understand what path a classloader or all classloaders are taking when I run my application using `java -jar myapp.jar` ?

so I am wondering if there is any tool that can show me how classes are getting loaded one by one and the name of the classloader that loaded a particular class ? This would be super helpful to debug application else I feel like I am shooting in the dark.

Comment: have you tried `java -verbose` ps: this will generate quite a large log

Comment: just tried `java -verbose -jar myapp.jar`. It isn't very helpful..

Comment: If verbose doesn't help, have you tried a debugger? If that doesn't help I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: for completeness, you can also use: java -Xlog:class+load=trace

Comment: @VicenteRomero that option doesn't seem to work on hotspot JVM.. Does that work on OpenJDK?
```Unrecognized option: -Xlog:class+load=trace
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.```

Comment: @user1870400 yes it works for me on OpenJDK for JDK10 and JDK9, it seems like it was introduced in 9 as version 8 issues the error you described

Comment: @JDK 10?? when is that released or when will it be released?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Java Flight Recorder and Java Mission Control.

In the recording wizard you can check Class Loading and the JVM will record the class, timestamp, thread, stack trace, defining and initiating class loader.

You could also turn on logging.

Comment: where do I get Java Flight Recorder and Java Mission Control ?

Comment: java mission control is shipped in every public JDK release. I think since 9 or probably 8. This tutorial seems like a good starting point:


   https://blog.takipi.com/oracle-java-mission-control-the-ultimate-guide/

Comment: JMC/JFR is included since JDK 7u40. Section 2.2-2.5 in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/toc.html might also be useful, or one of many youtube videos on the topic.

Comment: JMC 5.5 doesnt always launch on macos. I tried deleting ~/.jmc still doesnt launch..There seems to be process running however I dont see any UI.

Comment: The version of JMC 5.5(.1) which is bundled with the latest JDK8 updates does not work on new versions of MacOS. The same version of JMC bundled with the latest version of JDK 7 updates should work however.